# Convert datetime column using function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a dataframe with a column of datetimes. 
I'm trying to get the top answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299500/pandas-how-to-know-if-its-day-or-night-using-timestamp) to work on my dataframe.

```
def sunrise(timee):

 sun = ephem.Sun()
 observer = ephem.Observer()
 # ↓ Define your coordinates here ↓
 observer.lat, observer.lon, observer.elevation = '48.730302', '9.149483', 400
 # ↓ Set the time (UTC) here ↓
 observer.date = timee
 sun.compute(observer)
 current_sun_alt = sun.alt
 return current_sun_alt * 180 / math.pi

ClimateDF.insert(1, 'datetime', pd.to_datetime(ClimateDF.index)) #Index is date time!
ClimateDF['datetime'] = ClimateDF['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
ClimateDF['datetime'] = sunrise(ClimateDF['datetime'])
```

I can't figure it out. What am I missing?
I am currently getting:

```
 raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to " "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do `return current_sun_alt * 180 / math.pi` instead of printing it.

Comment: I updated it, see above. However still having an error - TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: You should `apply` this function, like this `ClimateDF['datetime'] = ClimateDF['datetime'].apply(sunrise)`. Are you sure that your input and output columns are the same `datetime`? Consider naming output  column differently, that way if something goes wrong during conversion, you can fix your function and apply it again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's some missing code in your question, as you have `def sunrise(timee):` but no function body at all. However, I see a problem here:

```
ClimateDF['datetime'] = ClimateDF['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
ClimateDF['datetime'] = sunrise(ClimateDF['Day/Night2'])
```

You never create a column called `Day/Night2`. Did you mean to create a column by that name? `ClimateDF['Day/Night2'] = sunrise(ClimateDF['datetime'])`

Comment: Nope, should have been datetime. Not sure about the function body?